Is the geoid a redshift isosurface?
This question is inspired by this question about timekeeping.
I understand the geoid to be the surface matching the shape that the water on Earth's crust would take

Under the effect of Earth's gravity
under the effect of Earth's rotation
If shallow channels were cut through Earth's landmasses (so that the shape could be estimated even in regions where land is present)
Ignoring the effects of winds and tides

Is the geoid ALSO a surface of constant gravitational redshift? I think if there was no rotation in the problem it would be obvious that, yes, this is a surface of constant redshift. Is that still the case when there is "bulging" at the equator due to centrifugal forces?

This question is similar to: Does time move slower at the equator?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
